# Update existing value in database using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update my table `contentment`, which has the following attributes:

> **employeeid, questionid, date**, score, comment

The words in bold are the `primary key` of this table. My `stored procedure` needs to `update` a `questionid` for a `employeeid`. Only the `questionid` needs to be changed. The `employeeid`, `date`, `score` and `comment` need to stay the same.

I have the following:

```
create procedure [dbo].[spUpdateContentment]
(   
@employeeid int,
@questionid int,
@date date            
)
as    
begin

     update contentment
     set questionid= @questionid
     where employeeid= @employeeid and questionid= @questionid and date = @date
else 
    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg,16,1)
end
```

But this is not working, it does nothing. I think this is because my stored procedure does not exactly know where he needs to update it, and which questionid he needs to update. But I'm not sure. I use SQL Server

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Maybe it has to be: and questionid != @questionid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing any values, therefore it does nothing. You may need the following:

```
create procedure [dbo].[spUpdateContentment]
(   
@employeeid int,
@new_questionid int,
@old_questionid int,
@date date            
)
as    
begin

     update contentment
     set questionid= @new_questionid
     where employeeid= @employeeid and questionid= @old_questionid and date = @date
else 
    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg,16,1)
end
```

Comment: Okay I think this is useful. The new questionid comes from a textbox in my programme, so this is clear which number it is and where it comes from. But the old questionid I don't know where the user can get this from? I think it is a bit silly if the user needs to insert the old questionid somewhere. Maybe the old questionid can just be @questionid? Thanks.

Comment: "Maybe the old questionid can just be @questionid?"

Comment: "Maybe the old questionid can just be @questionid?"

That's correct based upon your requirements. It is unusual to be updating the key of the row and even more unusual to build a stored proc to do it (i.e. doing it on a regular basis). Why does a question_id change while the score remains the same? If there's a valid reason for a question_id changing then why is it part of the primary key? These are questions you need to raise when creating the specification.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
 update contentment
     set questionid = @questionid
     where employeeid = @employeeid and date = @date;
```

The condition `and questionid = @questionid` is going to prevent the row being found.  If it is found, the `update` won't be changing any values.

It is possible that the logic requires two `@questionid`s, one for the old value and one for the new value.

Comment: Still I got same results (no update for the employeeid, it updates nothing). I also think this is because an employeeid can have multiple questions.